# Did a galaxy get discovered more than 30 billion light-years away? How does one observe light older than the estimated age of the universe?

Tags: light, distances

I'm more into questioning mainstream science and pseudo-science to remain open-minded.

*Why is it that we are seeing light 30 billion light years away; when the estimated age of the universe is much younger?
How does space-stretching circumvent the light-speed limit?*

Comment: Well, such a galaxy was a lot closer to us (under 30 million light-years away) when the light we see from it now started on its journey. Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1001/16685

Comment: @PM2Ring - Isn't your comment an answer?

Comment: @Mark I suppose it's the start of an answer, but I'm pretty sure we already have a good answer for this question already on the site. I'm hoping that we get some feedback from Travis to help us select an appropriate duplicate target.